# Adding static and instance methods to List in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, klaxon

I'm trying to add [Kotlin support](https://github.com/quicktype/quicktype/pull/838/files) to quicktype so that Kotlin developers can easy generate types and marshaling code in Kotlin from JSON.

For any given JSON sample, I want to generate a type `T` with a `T.fromJson` static method and a `T.toJson` instance method, but I am stuck when the top-level type is not an object. For example, given the JSON

```
[
  { "name": "David" }
]
```

`quicktype sample.json -t People -l kotlin` produces:

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   val people = People.fromJson(jsonString)

import com.beust.klaxon.*

private val klaxon =
    Klaxon()

typealias People = List<Person>

data class Person (
    val name: String
) {
    public fun toJson() = klaxon.toJsonString(this as Any)

    companion object {
        public fun fromJson(json: String) = klaxon.parse<Person>(json)
    }
}
```

What I need to do now is figure out how to add the `fromJson` and `toJson` methods to the `People` type. Here was my first attempt:

```
open class People {
    public fun toJson() = klaxon.toJsonString(this as Any)

    companion object {
        public fun fromJson(json: String) = klaxon.parseArray<Person>(json)
    }
}
```

But I could not write `open class People` so I removed the alias:

```
open class List<Person> {
    public fun toJson() = klaxon.toJsonString(this as Any)

    companion object {
        public fun fromJson(json: String) = klaxon.parseArray<Person>(json)
    }
}
```

But now `people.toJson()` does not compile because the compiler cannot find the method.

Can I accomplish the semantics I want in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
class People : List<Person>()
```

However personally I would simplify with the following generic top-level functions:

```
fun <T> T.toJson() = Klaxon().toJsonString(this as Any)
fun <T> fromJson(json: String) = Klaxon().parse<T>(json)
fun <T> fromJsonArray(json: String) = Klaxon().parseArray<T>(json)
```

Comment: These are great suggestions, thank you! My goal is for all `Json -> T` functions to be called `fromJson` though. Can I accomplish that with these top-level definitions?

Comment: I ended up subclassing `ArrayList` for the semantics I want. Works well! https://app2.quicktype.io?share=lOhEpg2Id0V7VrchxeRH